Genus of a graph consisting of two faces homeomorphic to open disks
Suppose the graph $G$ is embedded in a surface $Q$ such that there are two faces $F_1,F_2$ of the embedding, each homeomorphic to the open disk, such that each node of $G$ lies on $F_1$ or $F_2$.
Is the genus of $G$ necessarily a constant?

Also, what definition of the genus of a graph are you using? The definition that I know assigns, to every graph, a well-defined (and therefore constant) value... so, either you are using a different definition or there is some mis-understanding going on.

@LeeMosher I mean is there a constant $c$ such that if $G$ is a graph  embedded in a surface $Q$ such that there are two faces $F_1,F_2$ of the embedding, each homeomorphic to the open disk, such that each node of $G$ lies on $F_1$ or $F_2$. Then the genus of $G$ is at most $c$?

Is "each node of $G$ lies on $F_1$ or $F_2$" redundant, since every vertex is on the boundary of at least one face, and those are the only faces? (More for clarity than a criticism)

@aschepler the graph can consist of more than 2 faces but there are two faces (each homeomorphic to a disk) such that each node of $G$ lies on one of the two faces

Okay. The title's "graph consisting of two faces" sounds wrong then.

And based on your other comment, I think you want to ask if the genus of $G$ is bounded, not if it's constant.

One thing to keep in mind: a graph, all by itself, has no faces at all. It has only vertices and edges. So your comment saying that the graph can consist of more than 2 faces makes no sense. But, when a graph $G$ is embedded in a surface $S$, then it may have faces, namely, the components of $S-G$, assuming those components are open discs. One might say that the graph $G$ has faces relative to its embedding in $S$.

When you say "genus of $G$", I presume you mean the genus of the surface $Q$ into which $G$ is embedded, since (as pointed out in the comments) each graph has a fixed—and therefore constant—genus.
Then, the answer to your question is negative.
For, consider the planar graph $G = K_4^-$, which is obtained from the complete graph $K_4$ by deleting an edge. Fix a planar embedding of $G$, and let $C$ be the outer cycle in this embedding. Then,

$C$ is the boundary of (a region homeomorphic to) a closed disc $D$ in the plane;
there are exactly two bounded faces $F_1$ and $F_2$ in this embedding, and they satisfy the following conditions:

both are contained in the interior of $D$;
both are homeomorphic to open discs;
each vertex of $G$ lies on $F_1$ or $F_2$.



Now, for any orientable surface $Q$, delete a small closed disc and insert $D$ in its place. Then, this defines an embedding of $G$ into $Q$ that satisfies all the requirements.
But $Q$ was arbitrary, so there cannot be any bound on its genus.

The following paper might also be relevant/interesting in the context of this problem: Ringeisen, Richard D., Graphs of given genus and arbitrarily large maximum genus. Discrete Math. 6, 169–174 (1973). Zbl 0284.57013. Also see: Xuong, Nguyen Huy, How to determine the maximum genus of a graph.
J. Comb. Theory, Ser. B 26, 217–225 (1979). Zbl 0403.05035
